# Is there a Spring boot SAML client for integrating SAML with spring boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, adfs, azure-ad-msal, spring-saml

I am developing a spring boot application that integrates with multiple Idp's. I have checked many examples over the internet on integrating Spring application with SAML, all of them show how to integrate with IDP's via application properties.

In the case of OAuth 2.0, we had Clients provided by MSAL libraries, we integrated as below.

```
ConfidentialClientApplication
                    .builder(decryptCredential(adClientId), clientSecret)
                    .authority(authorityURL).build();
clientApplication.getAuthorizationRequestUrl(parameters).toString();
clientApplication.acquireToken(authorizationCodeParameters);
```

Is there a similar way in Spring boot, to have a Client call to ADFS SAMLIDP and get the user authenticated?

Based on the request, fetch IDP details from Database and invoke a call to the appropriate IDP to get the user authenticated.

thanks in advance.

Comment: i dont know much about SAML but there is a huge chapter about it in the spring security documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-saml2login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I explored coveooss library, which has clients and it is easiest one to invoke ADFS to fetch SAML assertions. Here is the link for [COVEOOSS git link](https://github.com/coveooss/saml-client)